# Vue this.$http.delete() returns 500 internal server only

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, axios, http-delete

I'm using axios to connect mysql db with vue frontend, and it's almost done. But the problem is that this.$http.delete() somehow doesn't work at all. I've looked it up but those solutions didn't work. (wrap it {data: book_no}, or {params: book_no}). But it seems like I need to wrap it anyway as an object from vue component when I request(for delete only) the data(req.body.book_no gets undefined data. that's why I added), so I tried few different formats, but it only returns 500 internal server error. Which makes even more 'what?????????' because almost same format of other functions(CRU) are working perfectly.

Please help me out this this.$http.delete method!

Frontend vue component:

```
btnDelete(book) {
  // console.log(book_no);
  let book_no = book.book_no;
  if (confirm(book_no + " 를 삭제하시겠습니까?")) {
    this.$http
      .delete("/api/books/delbook", {
          book: {
            book_no
          }
      })
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res.data);
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  } else {
    return;
  }
```

Backend Books.js delete part

```
router.delete('/delbook', function (req, res) {
    console.log(123)
    let bookNo = req.body.book.book_no
    console.log(bookNo)

    let bookObj = {
        'book_no': bookNo
    }

    console.log(bookObj)

    let sql = `DELETE FROM books WHERE book_no = ${bookNo}`
    console.log(6666)

    db.query(sql, bookObj, function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(err)
        console.log(result)
        console.log(3234234)
        res.send(result)
    })
})
```

error(the only error I've got):
DELETE http://localhost:8080/api/books/delbook 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Relevant documentation: https://github.com/axios/axios#axiosdeleteurl-config The method `axios.delete` does not take `data` as its second argument. Contrast that with other methods such as `axios.post`. The reason it doesn't take `data` as the second argument is because `DELETE` requests typically don't use a request body to communicate the relevant id. Some clients/servers don't even support a body for `DELETE`. I suggest you debug this further by carefully studying precisely what request is sent in the Network tab of the browser's developer tools.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but that's the problem. I've read all their doc but none of them worked. I know delete doesn't have data and ofc it's not gonna work out. The delete method doesn't work at all.

Comment: While I would discourage the design decision to use a request body for a `DELETE` request, I would have expected `this.$http.delete("/api/books/delbook", { data: { book: { book_no } })` to have worked given you current server implementation. The 500 error message is largely irrelevant from a debugging perspective.  You just need to use the Network tab of the browser's developer tools to check that **exactly** the right request is being sent and then throw in some extra logging on the server to establish why that isn't being handled correctly. Log `req.body`, not `bookNo`.

Comment: Hey, Thanks a lot for the help. I checked network before but it didn't show exact error that's why I was lost. and about { data: {book: {book_no}}}, I don't know why but somehow that format also didn't work so I checked req.body and sovled the issue. I don't know why I didn't check the reg.body log at the first place. Anyway! Many thanks for the help!